# Oracle Query saying an error AM/PM required

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I am getting an error in the query, what is wrong in this, always saying AM/PM required.

```
select RECORDTYPE, FILEID, SETOFBOOKSNAME, COSTCENTRE, GLACCOUNT, PRODUCT,
CUSTOMERSEGMENT, SUBLEDGER, JOURNALSOURCENAME, JOURNALCATEGORY, EFFECTIVEDATE ,
CURRENCYCODE, ENTEREDDR, ENTEREDCR, CONVERSIONTYPE, CURRENCYCONVERSIONDATE, 
CURRENCYCONVERSIONRATE, CONVERTEDDR, CONVERTEDCR, BATCHNAME, BATCHDESCRIPTION, 
JOURNALNAME, JOURNALDESCRIPTION, SOURCESYSTEMREFERENCE, JOURNALLINEDESCRIPTION 

from glaccount gl 

where EFFECTIVEDATE BETWEEN 
to_timestamp('2012-07-11 16:00:00.021 AM','DD-mm-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') and 
to_timestamp('2012-07-11 23:59:59.021 AM','DD-mm-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')
```

Comment: you don't need AM/PM if you are using HH24 time.  And your format doesn't match your timestamp input, should be 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `AM` (from the date itself) and set the date according to your formatting. It should be changed to:

```
to_timestamp('2012-07-11 16:00:00.021','YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS.FF')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
to_timestamp('2012-07-11 16:00:00.021 AM','DD-mm-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')
```

is wrong. You should change

`2012-07-11` to `11-07-12`

or

`DD-mm-RR` to `yyyy-mm-dd`

**UPDATE**: after this, you'll get

> hour must be between 1 and 12

because 16 AM does not exists, but that's another problem, simpler.